# Formatted JavaScript Date is one day behind

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a date: `yyyy-mm-dd` that I am formatting using the [International DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) like this:

```
const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", { month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', year: 'numeric', timeZone:'America/Denver'});

// GiVES SAME RESULTS AS ABOVE
//const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", { month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', year: 'numeric'}); 
//const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("default" , { month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', year: 'numeric'});

let date = "2020-03-19"
return formatter.format(Date.parse(date));

//returns 03/18/2020 which is one day behind
```

**I've tried this with and without the timeZone attribute**. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ECMAScript Date Time String Format](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format) defines formats for both date-time forms as well as date-only forms.  These are used by the `Date.parse` function and the `Date` constructor when a string is passed.  Behavior for those functions is defined in [the docs for the `Date.parse` function](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-date.parse), which contain the following statement:

> ... When the UTC offset representation is absent, date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time and date-time forms are interpreted as a local time.

Thus, when you call `Date.parse('2020-03-19')` the defined behavior is to treat that as UTC, not as local time.  (This deviates from ISO 8601.)

To change this behavior, append a time string or a time+offset string.

For example, if you want to parse the time in the local computer's time zone:

```
Date.parse('2020-03-19T00:00:00.000')
```

Or, if you want to parse in a particular time zone and know the correct offset for the given timestamp in that time zone:

```
Date.parse('2020-03-19T00:00:00.000-05:00')
```

Often one doesn't know the offset, but does know the IANA time zone identifiers (such as `'America/Chicago'`).  Unfortunately, ECMAScript doesn't currently have the capability to parse in a named time zone yet.  That capability will be possible if/when [the TC39 Temporal proposal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/) is adopted.  Until then, you could use a library such as [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) to perform such an action.  For example:

```
luxon.DateTime.fromISO('2020-03-19', { zone: 'America/Chicago' }).toString()
//=> "2020-03-19T00:00:00.000-05:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

`Date.parse("2020-03-19")` indicates 2020-03-19 00:00:00 GMT, so it will be 2020-03-18 for America/Denver, which will be `2020-03-18 17:00:00 America/Denver`

```js
const formatter1 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", { month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', year: 'numeric', timeZone:'America/Denver'});

const formatter2 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", { month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', year: 'numeric'}); 



let date = "2020-03-19"
console.log(formatter1.format(Date.parse(date)));
console.log(formatter2.format(Date.parse(date)));
```

Comment: Well, you're not wrong.

Comment: @Wang - as I've stated in the OP I've tried this with and without the timeZone attribute and get the same result.

Comment: can you update your codebase that is using without timezone?

Comment: @reactFullStackDeveloper the second one shows the correct result.

Comment: i have updated answer which shows both result. @reactFullStackDeveloper

Comment: @Wang - please run your own code. Your results are incorrect. Both show a day behind

Comment: i understand the issue.
the default is the runtime's default time zone,

Comment: refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat timezone option.

Comment: your timezone is UTC minus 7, and mine is UTC plus 8, so on my end, second one shows 2020-03-19, and on your end, both shows 2020-03-18

Answer (score -1):

You have added time zone, because of that it convert date into that time zone and because of the zone it can be 1 day behind or next day.

Comment: @Patil - as I've stated in the OP I've tried this with and without the timeZone attribute and get the same result.